# DynamoDB/Dynalite query not returning query with nodejs

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to learn AWS DynamoDB and ran into a seemingly simple looking issue that I can't figure out.

I'm using [Dynalite](https://github.com/mhart/dynalite) running on nodejs locally.
The error is as follows;

{ [ValidationException: Either the KeyConditions or   KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.]
  message: 'Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: Mon Dec 21 2015 17:31:47 GMT+0200 (SAST),
  requestId: 'RHDFVDXQTI0VZUIRJSLGRZXJFQJQYWGJOGS0B4MUDSX3H3JSVWNR',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 0 }

My table is created as follows(code is stripped down for brevity);

```
var params = {
    TableName : "test",
    KeySchema: [       
      { AttributeName: "email", KeyType: "HASH" },  
      { AttributeName: "date", KeyType: "RANGE" }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "email", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "date", AttributeType: "N" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    }
}

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)) }
    } else   { console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)) }
})
```

Test data is loaded with the following;

```
var params = { 
    TableName: 'test',
        Item: {
            "email":   lowerCasedEmail,
            "date":    date,                                                
            "amount":  amount,
        }
    }

  dynamodbDoc.put(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
     } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
     }
  })
```

And then the failing query is as follows;

```
var params = {
    TableName: "test",    
    KeyConditionExpression: "email = :testmail",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":testmail": "rik@test.com"
    }
}

dynamodbDoc.query(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) { console.log(err) } 
   else {
      if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
             console.log('Nothing found.')
      } else { console.log(data) }
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. Dynalite doesn't handle KeyConditionExpression correctly.

Comment: For the status of this problem, I'm keeping an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/mhart/dynalite/issues/24).